# Get the path to current page which has an overlay

Tags: uri, modal-dialogs

I have a page on which there is an overlay. I'm able to get the overlay's path using current_path(). How can I get the page's path on which the overlay is loaded.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: I came across a similar question here : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7800/get-context-of-overlay-get-parent-page-information?rq=1 . In case this might be helpful for someone with the same problem